# Roblox Studio Lua if-statement in loop

Tags: loops, if-statement, lua, roblox

I have a Roblox Game in this game the time changes using the code on the Roblox Developer site([robloxdev.com](https://robloxdev.com)) I have been making a door with two unions called "open" and "closed". I want the door to be open between 10 in the morning and 5 in the evening. However the door won't open and it's not even bringing up the print open/close when it is the right time.

This is my current code Note: The script is in the same model (called: Door) as the two unions.

```lua
while true do
   if game.Lighting.ClockTime > 10 and game.Lighting.ClockTime < 17 then
        --Open the door
        print("open")
        script.Parent.Closed.Transparency = 1
        script.Parent.Closed.CanCollide = false

        script.Parent.Open.Transparency = 0
        script.Parent.Open.CanCollide = true
    else
        --Close the door
        print("close")
        script.Parent.Closed.Transparency = 0
        script.Parent.Closed.CanCollide = true

        script.Parent.Open.Transparency = 1
        script.Parent.Open.CanCollide = false
    end
end
```

Thank's for any help.

Comment: I may have missed it, but whats the issue you are looking for assistance with? is the door not doing what you expect? is the whole game seeming to freeze up?

Comment: sorry I never said that the door won't open, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: are you updating `Lighting.ClockTime`? [this property does not correspond with the actual time of day and will not change during the game unless it has been changed by a script.](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Lighting/ClockTime)

Comment: You might also need to add a `wait()` inside the `while true` loop but outside the `if` statement.

Comment: Yes I said I was using the Roblox Code for changing the time which is DEFINITELY working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add wait inside the while loop.

```
while true do
   if game.Lighting.ClockTime > 10 and game.Lighting.ClockTime < 17 then
        --Open the door
        print("open")
        script.Parent.Closed.Transparency = 1
        script.Parent.Closed.CanCollide = false

        script.Parent.Open.Transparency = 0
        script.Parent.Open.CanCollide = true
    else
        --Close the door
        print("close")
        script.Parent.Closed.Transparency = 0
        script.Parent.Closed.CanCollide = true

        script.Parent.Open.Transparency = 1
        script.Parent.Open.CanCollide = false
    end
    wait(1) -- change this to whatever you want
end
```